# Consuming RabbitMQ messages with Spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rabbitmq, spark-streaming

I'm new to scala and trying to hack my way around sending serialized Java objects over a RabbitMQ queue to a Spark Streaming application.

I can successfully enqueue my objects which have been serialized with an `ObjectOutputStream`. To receive my objects on the Spark end I have downloaded a custom RabbitMQ `InputDStream` and `Receiver` implementation from here - https://github.com/Stratio/rabbitmq-receiver

However, in my understanding that codebase only supports `String` messages, not binary. Thus I started hacking on that code in order to make it support being able to read a binary message and store it as a byte array, so that I can deserialize it on the Spark end. That attempt is here - https://github.com/llevar/rabbitmq-receiver

I then have the following code in my Spark driver program:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[6]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))

val receiverStream: ReceiverInputDStream[scala.reflect.ClassTag[AnyRef]]  =
  RabbitMQUtils.createStreamFromAQueue(ssc, 
                                       "localhost", 
                                       5672, 
                                       "mappingQueue", 
                                       StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)
val parsedStream = receiverStream.map{ m =>
  SerializationUtils.deserialize(m.asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]).asInstanceOf[SAMRecord]
}
parsedStream.print()
ssc.start()
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. The data is consumed off the queue. I don't get any errors but I don't get any of the output that I expect either.

This is all I get.

> 2015-07-24 23:33:38 WARN  BlockManager:71 - Block input-0-1437795218845 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
>   2015-07-24 23:33:38 WARN  BlockManager:71 - Block input-0-1437795218846 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
>   2015-07-24 23:33:38 WARN  BlockManager:71 - Block input-0-1437795218847 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
>   2015-07-24 23:33:38 WARN  BlockManager:71 - Block input-0-1437795218848 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers

I was able to successfully deserialize my objects before calling the store() method here - https://github.com/llevar/rabbitmq-receiver/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/stratio/receiver/RabbitMQInputDStream.scala#L106

just by invoking `SerializationUtils` on the data from the `delivery.getBody` call, but I don't seem to be able to get the same data from the `DStream` in my main program.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you able to resolve this issue.